# Кран закривають чи закручують?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, дієслова

> [Кран](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44775&page=1417) Пристрій, прикріплений до водопроводу, газопроводу, якогось
>   резервуару для виливання рідини, випускання газу, а також для
>   перекриття трубопроводу. *Ватя ледве встигла поставити чайник на стіл
>   і закрутити кран самовара* (І. Нечуй-Левицький)

Хоча в прикладі і є слово ["закрутити"](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=30052&page=987), на мою думку не підходить для всіх видів кранів (наприклад, на малюнку точно не закручується). 
[image]

Чи можна сказати закрити кран чи правильно лише закрутити?

Answer (score 1):

Гадаю, що все може залежати від виду крану, а саме від виду його [ручки](http://kanalizaciyadoma.com.ua/remont-kranov.gif). Ми точно можемо сказати "закрутити кран", дивимося визначення слова "[кран](http://sum.in.ua/s/kran)" в СУМі:

> Трубка з затвором, прикріплена до водопроводу, газопроводу чи іншого
>   резервуару для виливання рідини, випускання газу.

Тут же приклади:

> Батя ледве встигла поставити чайник на стіл і **закрутити кран** самовара
>   (Нечуй-Левицький, IV, 1956, 64); Господарка раптом побачила, що з
>   крана тік тоненький, блискучий струмочок води, і похапцем **закрутила
>   колісце** (Олесь Досвітній, Вибр., 1959, 232).

Я так розумію, це стосується кранів із ручками такого типу як на картинці:

[image]

А також бачимо, що одне із значень слова "[закручувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zakruchuvaty)" є таке:

> Загвинчуючи, укріпляти в чомусь, закривати що-небудь.

Тобто мається на увазі, що ми замикаємо щось роблячи колоподібні рухи.

На крані на вашій картинці встановлена ручка-важіль, яка рухається лише вверх або вниз, тому можна вжити словосполучення "[перекрити](http://sum.in.ua/s/perekryvaty) кран":

> Закривати, перегороджувати чим-небудь рух води, пари

І я не впевнений, але можливо і справді можна сказати "закрити кран" беручи до уваги, що слово закрити може мати таке переносне значення:

> Робити недоступним, неможливим для проходу, проникнення кого-,
>   чого-небудь.

Якщо ж кран електричний, то його можна "[вимкнути](http://sum.in.ua/s/vymykaty)" (у нього може й не бути ручок).

Comment: В розмовній мові  слово "закручувати" можна вживати практично для всіх дій що робиться круговими рухами.
В технічній літературі зі словом "кран" прийнято вживати термін "закривають". Особливо у випадках , коли розрізняють поняття "кран" (менше одного оберту між закритим та відкритим положеннями) і  "вентиль" (більше одного оберту).